# MySQL: Get column name or alias from query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm not asking for the `SHOW COLUMNS` command.

I want to create an application that works similarly to heidisql, where you can specify an SQL query and when executed, returns a result set with rows and columns representing your query result. The column names in the result set should match your selected columns as defined in your SQL query.

In my Python program (using `MySQLdb`) my query returns only the row and column results, but not the column names.  In the following example the column names would be `ext`, `totalsize`, and `filecount`.  The SQL would eventually be external from the program.

The only way I can figure to make this work, is to write my own SQL parser logic to extract the selected column names.

Is there an easy way to get the column names for the provided SQL?
Next I'll need to know how many columns does the query return?

```
# Python

import MySQLdb

#===================================================================
# connect to mysql
#===================================================================

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="myhost", user="myuser", passwd="mypass",db="mydb")
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)

#===================================================================
# query select from table
#===================================================================

cursor = db.cursor ()   

cursor.execute ("""\
     select ext,
        sum(size) as totalsize,
        count(*) as filecount
     from fileindex
    group by ext
    order by totalsize desc;
""")

while (1):
    row = cursor.fetchone ()
    if row == None:
        break
    print "%s %s %s\n" % (row[0], row[1], row[2])

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: cursor.column_names

Answer (score 292, accepted):

cursor.description will give you a tuple of tuples where [0] for each is the column header.

```
num_fields = len(cursor.description)
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
```

Comment: cursor.column_names does it too

Comment: In MySQLdb 1.2.5 `cursor.column_names` is missing.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko .column_names is gone? I need to use .description to get the column names?

Comment: @SteveS from what I wrote last year it seems that :)

Comment: To make it shorter: `field_names = next(zip(*cursor.description))`

Answer (score 47):

This is the same as [thefreeman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14027898) but in a more Pythonic way using list and dictionary comprehension

```py
columns = cursor.description 
result = [{columns[index][0]:column for index, column in enumerate(value)} for value in cursor.fetchall()]

pprint.pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 35):

Similar to @James answer, a more pythonic way can be:

```
fields = [field_md[0] for field_md in cursor.description]
result = [dict(zip(fields,row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

You can get a single column with list comprehension over the result:

```
extensions = [row['ext'] for row in result)
```

or filter results using an additional if in the list comprehension:

```
large = [row for row in result if row['filesize'] > 1024 and row['filesize'] < 4096]
```

or accumulate values for filtered columns:

```
totalTxtSize = reduce(
        lambda x,y: x+y,
        filter(lambda x: x['ext'].lower() == 'txt', result)
)
```

Comment: Thorough.  Is there an advantage to using fetchall over iterating on the cursor?

Comment: @kzarns: I'd say that making the example shorter, and getting a full list. You might create a generator function instead that iterates over the cursor, using `yield`, and might use less memory.

Comment: Doesn't work with me, only the first row is converterted, slightly adaption to make it work: `fields = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]`  then  `result = [dict(zip(fields,row))  for row in cursor.fetchall()]` wil work

Comment: Very nice. You could also create a `DataFrame` from `result` with `pd.DataFrame.from_records` and do all that filtering and aggregation in pandas.   
Although, if you are up to using pandas, it might be easier to use sqlalchemy and pd.read_sql in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

I think this should do what you need (builds on the answer above) .  I am sure theres a more pythony way to write it, but you should get the general idea.

```
cursor.execute(query)
columns = cursor.description
result = []
for value in cursor.fetchall():
    tmp = {}
    for (index,column) in enumerate(value):
        tmp[columns[index][0]] = column
    result.append(tmp)
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Comment: is there any other simple way, why it does not return value with fields?

Answer (score 9):

You could also use `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`. This turns your result set into a python list of python dictionaries, although it uses a special cursor, thus technically less portable than the accepted answer. Not sure about speed. Here's the edited original code that uses this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

#===================================================================
# connect to mysql
#===================================================================

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='myhost', user='myuser', passwd='mypass', db='mydb', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print 'Error %d: %s' % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

#===================================================================
# query select from table
#===================================================================

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = 'SELECT ext, SUM(size) AS totalsize, COUNT(*) AS filecount FROM fileindex GROUP BY ext ORDER BY totalsize DESC;'

cursor.execute(sql)
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()

print len(all_rows) # How many rows are returned.
for row in all_rows: # While loops always make me shudder!
    print '%s %s %s\n' % (row['ext'], row['totalsize'], row['filecount'])

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Standard dictionary functions apply, for example, `len(row[0])` to count the number of columns for the first row, `list(row[0])` for a list of column names (for the first row), etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point, but I was writing a utility where the query varies and I need to support the field order in the query.  Dictionary cursor has no ordering to the fields.

Comment: What we need is an ordereddict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504938/pymysql-and-ordereddict

Answer (score 9):

This is only an add-on to the accepted answer:

```
def get_results(db_cursor):
    desc = [d[0] for d in db_cursor.description]
    results = [dotdict(dict(zip(desc, res))) for res in db_cursor.fetchall()]
    return results
```

where `dotdict` is:

```
class dotdict(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

This will allow you to access much easier the values by column names.
Suppose you have a `user` table with columns `name` and `email`:

```
cursor.execute('select * from users')
results = get_results(cursor)
for res in results:
  print(res.name, res.email)
```

Answer (score 5):

Something similar to the proposed solutions, only the result is json with `column_header : vaule` for `db_query` ie `sql`.

```py
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
res = [dict((cur.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

output json example:

```json
[
   {
      "FIRST_ROW":"Test 11",
      "SECOND_ROW":"Test 12",
      "THIRD_ROW":"Test 13"
   },
   {
      "FIRST_ROW":"Test 21",
      "SECOND_ROW":"Test 22",
      "THIRD_ROW":"Test 23"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cursor.column_names
```

mysql connector version:

```
mysql.connector.__version__
'2.2.9'
```

Comment: maybe it works for MySQL, but didn't work for sqlite for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MySQLdb doesn't actually provide a translation for that API call.  The relevant C API call is [`mysql_fetch_fields`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-fields.html), and [there is no MySQLdb translation for that](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysql-c-api-function-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this to just get the field titles:

```
table = cursor.description
check = 0
for fields in table:
    for name in fields:
        if check < 1:
            print(name),
        check +=1
    check =0
```

Comment: Very nice idea thanks! I really wanted to get the columns as a result of a query, and your suggestion provides a nice way ```<cursor>.execute('describe <table>')``` and then fetch

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.column_names` is a nice and simple one.

Comment: Already suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240974/5320906) from 2019.

Answer (score -1):

column_names = cursor.field_names

Comment: This is the same as this [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240974/5320906)

Answer (score -1):

found an easy way of having colums like sql using `pymysql` and `pandas`

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db  = pymysql.connect(host="myhost", user="myuser", passwd="mypass", db="mydb")

query  = """SELECT ext
              SUM(size) as totalsize,
              COUNT(*) as filecount
            FROM fileindex
            GROUP BY ext 
            ORDER BY totalsize DESC;
         """
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,db)
```

the DataFrame will have column names ext,totalsize,filecount by default no need to do additional stuff.

for example in my case:
[image]