# How to do a SELECT * following all foreign keys

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to do a SELECT statement that will get all the data in one table + follow all the foreign keys from that table with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. For example:

```
`orderitem`
id
name
title_id

`title`
id
name
```

In the above example, I would be able to use the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM orderitem LEFT OUTER JOIN title on orderitem.title_id=title.id
```

Is there a way that I could do this not knowing the table structure? That is, to have a function like the following:

```
def get_select_statement(table)
    ???

get_select_statement(orderitem)
==> "SELECT * FROM orderitem LEFT OUTER JOIN title on orderitem.title_id=title.id"
```

How would this be done?

To clarify this question, I think I'm looking for the following information from this function:

- What are all the column names in the given table?
- What tables do they reference in a ForeignKey relationship and what is the relationship to be able to join?

In addition, note that not all `orderitem`s will have a `title`, so doing any sort of `INNER JOIN` would delete data.

Comment: what SQL library / ORM are you using to model your tables?

Comment: very limited information to answer this. But your query should be inner join no left join

Comment: What if you did a `USING(name, id)` clause instead of the `ON` statement?

Comment: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Get column name or alias from query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010042/mysql-get-column-name-or-alias-from-query)

Comment: @Alex thanks, please see updated question.

Comment: @Pynchia -- mysql, MySQLdb, no ORM.

Comment: You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` to get the list of foreign keys, and then generate dynamic SQL that uses it in a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQLDB you could retrieve column names by using [describe statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html):

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

And all info about foreign keys:

```
select *
from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where TABLE_SCHEMA = "schema_name" 
      and TABLE_NAME="table_name" 
      and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

To evaluate this query and load the result in python you could use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) package, for example.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysqldb://user:password@host/db")
res = engine.execute("DESCRIBE table_name;")
columns = [row["Field"] for row in res]

res = engine.execute("{}".format(query_for_foreign_keys))
foreign_keys = [row["COLUMN_NAME"] for row in res]
referenced_column_names = [row["REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME"] for row in res]
referenced_table_names = [row["REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME"] for row in res]
```

Then you could generate the query using all the data above