# Call mysql stored procedure in python and write the result into a csv file

Tags: python, mysql

im new to python and Im trying to define a function in python that calls a stored procedure in python using mysql.connector and write the result into a csv file.
i have defined a function to call the stored procedure and print the result. But couldn't figure out how to write my result into a csv file instead of printing. Tried some methods found in web but didn't take me anywhere

so far my codes are:

```
def call_accessionsByaffliction():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="root", 
password="1232580", database="db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.callproc('AccessionsBycauseOfAffliction_year')
        for result in cur.stored_results():
            print(result.fetchall())
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

and

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_accessionsByaffliction()
```

Any help? Much appreciated

Comment: If you're going to write to a CSV, use the standard `csv` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

def cs_writer(string_chunk):
    # define desired output file name      
    file_name = "output.csv"
    try:
        #open file in write mode and hold object 
        out_file = open(file_name, "wt")

        # create csv write object
        writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for line in string_chunk:
            writer.writerow(line)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        # close file
        out_file.close()

def call_accessionsByaffliction():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="root", password="1232580", database="db")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        # execute stored procedure
        cur.callproc('AccessionsBycauseOfAffliction_year')

        # fetch all results or use fetchone()
        for res in cur.stored_results():
            result = res.fetchall()

        print(result)
        return result
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cur.close()
        conn.close() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cs_writer(call_accessionsByaffliction())
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is the code i was looking for. but im still getting an error saying: No result set to fetch from.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 2, in <module>
    call_accessionsByaffliction()
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 42, in call_accessionsByaffliction
    for row in result:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment. Any help to fix this? couldnt figure it out

Comment: @Dusha.9 I have made some changes in code can you try again ?

Comment: im still getting an error message saying: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 2, in <module>
    call_accessionsByaffliction()
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 25, in call_accessionsByaffliction
    writer.writerow(row)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Or instead of writing the csv file inside the "call_accessionsByaffliction()" function, can we write the result into a csv file after executing the function? any help? much appreciated

Comment: can you confirm if call_accessionsByafflication() is returning chunk of string and pass it to cs_writer()

Comment: this is the result set i got when i printed my results: [('Fell out of tree', datetime.date(2009, 4, 23), 1), ('Orphaned/Dependent Young', datetime.date(2009, 8, 10), 11), ('Surrendered/confiscated', datetime.date(2009, 5, 28), 28)]

Comment: can you also check main() if cs_writer() is being called or not? I see csv generation and data population.

Comment: Thanks heaps. this is working. and one more question, can i have headers in my csv file

Comment: yes you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010042/mysql-get-column-name-or-alias-from-query and get header and append it to result[0] location

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with data, I strongly recommend looking into Pandas. Also, for forums like this, it's best to leave out `__main__` checks. Here's an untested code which does the things you're trying to do in Pandas.

```
import pandas

connection_string = "'mysql://root:1232580@localhost/db'"
df = pandas.read_sql_query('EXEC AccessionsBycauseOfAffliction_year', connection_string)
df.to_csv('AccessionsBycauseOfAffliction_year.csv')
```

Comment: sorry i dont have pandas installed

Comment: It’s pretty easy to install: `pip install pandas`

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to find SP, for calling you can use following code 
Please give more formation that you want code only for storing result in csv??

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config


    def call_find_by_isbn():
        try:
            db_config = read_db_config()
            conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            args = ['1236400967773', 0]
            result_args = cursor.callproc('AccessionsBycauseOfAffliction_year', args)

            print(result_args[1])

        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        call_find_by_isbn()
```

Comment: yeah. im trying to save the results in a csv file. but still couldnt figure out a way

Comment: okay so you are able to find stored procedure only concern is storing result in CSV file will give you code, or you can try solution given by @chthonicdaemon

Comment: yes, my stored procedure is "AccessionsBycauseOfAffliction_year()", im looking for the code to store my result set in a csv file. i prefer using same method instead of using pandas. Any help?