# I retrieved data from MySQL database using python but attribute names are not displayed. How can i display data in python dictionary format?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r') 
import mysql.connector
import json

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
     user='root',
     password='',
     host='localhost',
     database='id1914180_myproducts')
     cur = conn.cursor()

     query = ("SELECT * FROM Reviews")

     cur.execute(query)
     result=cur.fetchall()
     print(json.dumps(result))

     cur.close()
     conn.close()
```

I want the data to be displayed in dictionary format like given:

[{'UserName':'Rozi','You Me and Dupree':2.5,'Lady in the water':4.0}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPLKC.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to print them in a pretty way ? Can you post your output from using this code ?

Comment: The output is in this format. Attribute names are important to me and it is not displaying that.                                                                                               
[["Rozi", 3.5, 0.0, 4.5, 2.0, 0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0], ["Ahmed", 0.0, 4.0, 3.5, 2.0, 0.0, 4.5, 0.0, 0.0], ["Amir", 5.0, 3.5, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]] @KALALEX

Comment: When you trerieve a query (with `cur.fetchall()`) you get the resulting table data not the column names. You need to parse them separately, you can access them from `cur.description` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010042/mysql-get-column-name-or-alias-from-query)

Comment: I get table data along column names in Python Notebook with same code  but it causes this problem when i run the script from my hosting.