# MySQL format and Flask Templates

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have made a small flask app that pulls data from a MySQL source and places it into a table, however, the MySQL data is not correctly populating the table. (edit - by this i mean it is not populating at all, my bad)

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=x,
    user=x,
    passwd=x,
    database=x
)
```

```
def browserSettings_mysql():
    curs = mydb.cursor()
    curs.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dtime, '%Y-%m-%d %T') as timest, moisture, temp FROM moisture")
    return curs.fetchall()
```

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
       return render_template("index.html", rows = moistureControl.browserSettings_mysql())
```

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Temp</th>
      <th>Moisture</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.timest}}</td>
        <td>{{row.temp}}</td>
        <td>{{row.moisture}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `moistureControl.browserSettings_mysql()` is actually returning the data you expect? If so what does that data look like?

Comment: @noslenkwah It came out as ```[('2020-04-28 06:45:51', 2.0, 2.0), ('2020-04-28 07:10:22', 90.0, 22.0)]``` when printed to the console. I'm not sure if the row titles should be included in the print or not, that might be causing it not to work though

Comment: @noslenkwah I created a work around by just calling the rows by their index (row[0], row[1], etc) but is there a way to output the mysql data with row titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rows object is a list of tuples. You will have to access the data by index (e.g. `row[0]` instead of `row.timest`).

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Temp</th>
      <th>Moisture</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

Comment: Is there any way to change how ```fetchall()``` outputs the data?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5010042/4032503) question. It sounds really close to what you are looking for.