# How to get column names SQL in python

Tags: python, mysql

I want get a db into pandas df  in Python. I use a following code:

```py
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
query = """
        SELECT * FROM `an_visit` AS `visit`                 
        JOIN `an_ip` AS `ip`  ON  (`visit`.`ip_id` = `ip`.`ip_id`)
        JOIN `an_useragent` AS `useragent` ON (`visit`.`useragent_id` = `useragent`.`useragent_id`)                 
        JOIN `an_pageview` AS `pageview`  ON (`visit`.`visit_id` = `pageview`.`visit_id`)       
        WHERE `visit`.`visit_id` BETWEEN  %s AND %s
        """
self.cursor.execute(query, (start_id, end_id))

df = pd.DataFrame(self.cursor.fetchall())
```

This code works, but I want to get column names as well. I tried this question [MySQL: Get column name or alias from query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010042/mysql-get-column-name-or-alias-from-query)

but this did not work:

```py
fields = map(lambda x: x[0], self.cursor.description)
result = [dict(zip(fields, row)) for row in self.cursor.fetchall()]
```

How can I get column names from db into df? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what do you mean by "get column names"? What is your desired output?

Comment: @sophocles now my df has names caled 1, 2, 3, ..., 25. I would like to have the same names, asi in the DB, which is `ip_id`, `useragent_i` etc.

Comment: when you say that the above code is not working, is it producing an error or not giving you the expected output?

Comment: @Jayvee I already solved it, see my answer, thank you for your effort!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What work to me is:

```
field_names = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.description ]
```

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to include column names within recordset is to set dictionary=True as following:

self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

Then, all of fetch(), fetchall() and fetchone() are return dictionary with column name and data

check out links:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html

https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/connection.html

Comment: THANK YOU! Why does this not have more likes. You saved me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a column_names properties in MySql cursor that you can use:

```
row = dict(zip(self.cursor.column_names, self.cursor.fetchone()))
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-column-names.html

Comment: I tried, but `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'column_names'`

Comment: are you connecting to a mysql DB?

Comment: yes, using `import pymysql as mysql` and `self.connection = mysql.connect()`

Comment: that's odd, are you qualifying it with "self" , I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes, I do it with `self` within the method.. Same error

Answer (score 0):

the best practice to list all the columns in the database is to execute this query form the connection cursor

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA='<schema>' AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
```

Comment: ok, can you write it so it pass to my example above? I don`t know how to modify it to my case.